# php выборка строк из файла .eml?

Tags: php

Как мне получить нужные строки из .eml файла?
Например мне нужны данные начиная со слов **To** и заканчивая **References**
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно извлечь данные из письма входящего письма, то вам нужно его сначала декодировать. Для этих целей используют функции типа https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.mailparse.php или на github есть разные библиотеки парсинга писем и извлечения их параметров и контента.